# Maximum of an array without using maxval in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I want to find the maximum of an array `T` without using `maxval` in the last 2 parts of my code (marked with `**`). Unfortunately, it isn't working. It diplays me all the numbers verified only with the if condition without finding the maximum of it. The if condition just takes the first number and compared to other and if verified, display it all I can't my find my error.

```
Program exo2

Implicit None 
Real, Dimension (:,:), Allocatable   :: D    
integer                              :: i,Z,A,B,ok
Real                                 :: no_esc_max=1 , no_esc_min=1
Real, Dimension(:)   , Allocatable   :: T                            

print*, "entrez le nombre etudies"
read*, A
print*, "entrez le nombre de mesures pour chaque escargot"
read*, B

Allocate(D(A,B), STAT=ok)
Allocate(T(A), STAT=ok)

if (ok/=0) then
    print* , "allocation a echoue"
    Stop
end if

Do i=1,A
   Do z=1,B
    Print*, "Escargot",i
    Print*,"entrez la vitesse lors de la mesure",z
    Read*, D(i,z)
   end do
end do

Do i=1,A
   print*, D(i,:)                                
end do                          

Do i=1,A
   Do z=1,B
   T(i)=Sum(D(i,:))/z
   end do
   print*, "moyenne escargot", i , T(i)
end do


! (**) This block seems to have the problem
no_esc_max=T(1)
do i=2,A
   if (no_esc_max<T(i)) then
      T(i)=no_esc_max
   end if
   print* , "escargot",i, "est le plus rapide"
end do

no_esc_min=T(1)
do i=2,A
  if (no_esc_min>T(i)) then 
     T(i)=no_esc_min
  end if 
  print*, "escargot", i, "est le moins rapide"
end do
! (**) End of the block

Deallocate (D)
Deallocate (T)

End Program exo2
```

Comment: Hi, your if statements are assigning the the found max to the `average snail-speed` and not the way around. On top of that, you need to keep track of an index. I suggest to do something like :: `if (no_esc_max<T(i)) then; no_esc_max=T(i); imax=i; end if` the fastest snail is then the one with `imax` as an index. I hope this helped your snail-race!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the correct i, you should keep track of the index refering to your max/min value. Additionally, put your print*,'..' commands outside the do-loop. Otherwise, it seems that you are just printing all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: maxloc would do this.